# Return URL is broken for escaped characters

Tags: bug, status-completed, hyperlinks, character-escaping

Another one about special chars in URLs.

Easy reproducing steps:

1. Go to the [C# tag page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/c%23)
2. Log in if you're logged out or log out if you're logged in.
3. You're now returned to the [C tag page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/c)

Gets worse, for example, when coming from a "answers:1" kind of search result page.

Answer (score 1):

Marking this completed, for now, but it's only partially complete.

I fixed the more common return URL errors.

One pernicious problem is that certain tags in URLs need to be *double* encoded, and the ReturnUrl() function has to somehow figure that out.

So, for now, we're bailing on that part of it. If you log in or out on a search containing a tag with a character that is sketchy in URLs like [c#] or [c++] it may not quite work right.

Answer (score 0):

I have the same issue:

1. Log out
2. Go to `https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged?tagnames=svn%20or%20subversion`
3. Log in
4. The `%` characters are escaped and you're taken to:
   `https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged?tagnames=svn%2520or%2520subversion`
   which is not valid.